# Store Flask blog content by using database or something else?

Tags: database, flask, static-site

I'm writing a Flask blog app.
I think that it some kind a heavy way to use database to store every post content. Is there a nicer way to implement this?
Is it a good way to use things like static site? If it's so, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want blog posts to be stored over multiple user sessions, you must use some kind of database and ORM. The most common ORM used with flask is [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/). There is lots of good documentation for using Flask and SQLAlchemy together.

However, if you are not married to Flask, [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) might be a good alternative, because it has a built in ORM and very good documentation for it already.

Extra: [You can get pretty far with Flask](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14026051)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. What I want to do is to write a personal blog app like [this](https://geelaw.blog/). I know SQLAlchemy and will use it for storing things like posts titles. What I wonder is that is it a good way to use database to store the post content and render it in the dynamic template to do things in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192339/include-specific-js-css-files-in-specific-blog-posts-a-flask-app). Is it a good try to set up an `assets` folder for each post like [this](https://geelaw.blog/) blog do (and that will be things like static site)?

Comment: You should be able to just store the blog content in another database field. You can have fields up to 2GB in size in SQL, I believe. In terms of the dynamic template, you could just pass boolean values into the `render_template` function determining if you need this libraries to run, and use an `if` statement within the template to call `<script>` block that loads the library.